# How to Have a Bundled Configurable Product in Magento?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, configurable-product

I've been searching about this topic on Magento forum and Google but can't find a definite answer for the question. Hope I find it here.

Is it possible to have a bundled configurable products in Magento?
Take for example I want to sell a set of t-shirt and short on a product page where the customer can choose the number of quantity, the color and the size for the t-shirt and short respectively.

Maybe like this :

> **T-Shirt**  [A configurable Product]
>
> Color : [combobox to select color]
>
> Size  : [combobox to select Size]
>
> Qty   : [input to enter the qty]
>
> ---
>
> **Short**  [Another configurable Product]
>
> Color : [combobox to select color]
>
> Size  : [combobox to select Size]
>
> Qty   : [input to enter the qty]
>
> ---
>
> [Add to Cart Button]

Any help and answer will be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve this? We are also looking at "packs of products" where a new product is created very similar to the original T-shirt in this example with 1 difference: when sold/returned etc stock needs to be changed by the pack size = 6

Answer (score 1):

We've released the previously mentioned package builder at http://www.tinybrick.com/magento-modules/sales-tools/magento-configurable-products-package-bundler.html

It's a pretty sweet solution for great upsells.

Comment: Is this still available? The link goes to a 404 page and I don't see anything like it on the rest of the site.

Answer (score 0):

We will be releasing a new Package Builder plug in for Magento in the next couple of weeks that will do this. Plus it will allow you to create a package with multiple components and each components gives you multiple selections.

You can view it working here:zumiez.com/guys-5-for-85.html

http://store.delorumcommerce.com/magento-package-builder.html