# Multi-part clothing store in Magento

Tags: magento

EDIT: This has been resolved thanks to: http://www.brimllc.com/2010/12/magento-grouped-products-containing-associated-configurable-products/

The guy who runs this blog was very, very helpful. We can now add configurable products to a grouped product. Problem solved.

I'm trying to do something very simple, but can't figure out how to execute.

We've got a Magento store that sells lingerie. Tops and bottoms that each have their own size.

So a customer could order a top in small and a bottom in medium.

On the front end, I need to customer to see:

Product name

Top: S, M, L (dropdown)
Bottom: S, M, L (dropdown)

Just can't figure out how to do this in the Magento admin. Each product is entered as a simple product with the attribute "size" defined: "Small" for example.

But, when I create a configurable product and select the attributes "sizes_tops" & "sizes_bottoms" it only allows me to select products that have both defined, so obviously that won't work.

How on earth do I do this simply in Magento?

We could also have a situation where there are two types of bottoms to choose from, like full and g-string.

If there wasn't the restriction on adding simple products to a configurable product with only one of the attributes defined I'd be all set (I think anyway).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have seen this post: [How to Have a Bundled Configurable Product in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947433/how-to-have-a-bundled-configurable-product-in-magento)

classyllama.com/configurable-bundle-module - "Note: At this point, we are selling this bundle as-is. ie, we are not providing implementation support for this module. If you purchase the module and it doesn't work for your needs, we can deactivate your license and refund your money." - So it seems there is no support for the product, not very promising.

mag-manager - Site does not load

tinybrick- Does not fit the requirements

Answer (score 0):

As you intimated in your post, this is not something that is possible with a vanilla installation of Magento. Having (attempted) to implement this feature repeatedly in the past, I can also say that it is highly complex and difficult to accomplish.

Hopefully, one of those modules will work well for you. Ask to see a live customer site with the module installed to get an idea of whether it will work. If not, you will be in for a significant implementation effort.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thanks Joe. I found this post: http://www.brimllc.com/2010/12/magento-grouped-products-containing-associated-configurable-products/ Seems promising, we'll see. None of the modules I posted will work it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just have to define your tops and bottoms make them configurable separately and then make grouped items over tops and bottoms

Answer (score 0):

We have turned our blog post into an easy to install module called [Grouped Options](http://ecommerce.brimllc.com/grouped-options.html). Simple products with required custom options and configurable products can now be associated with grouped products in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but for anyone that is coming across this post now, Classy Llama Studios has released a new version of the Configurable Bundle extension and it is supported.  You can find it here: [Configurable Bundle Module on Classy Llama's Store](http://store.classyllama.com/configurable-bundle-module)